# 3D image (drag&drop,editing,rotation,resize,zoom in & zoom out) using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2.0, silverlight-2-rc0

i am new to silverlight, learning basics now.
But i need to implement 3D image manipulation(drag&drop,editing,rotation,resize,zoom in & zoom out).
Please explain with corresponding code samples,attachments .
Please as soon as possible.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645575.

Comment: This question has an answer with upvotes. Voting to close previous version.

Comment: not only a duplicate question, duplicate poster!

Comment: is there a tag along the lines of 'do-my-job-for-me'?

Answer (score 5):

surendra-chw,

This is a very open-ended question: it will be difficult for people to help you unless you are clear about exactly what you are trying to accomplish (and please explain what you have already tried/learned, if anything). Most importantly, in a question-answer environment like **stackoverflow** we can't do your work for you.

Silverlight 2.0 does not support *any* 3D functionality out-of-the-box. I guess you knew that?

You have probably already found [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) via google? It attempts to provide a subset of the WPF 3D namespaces/classes to give you a consistent API where possible. It also contains a sample project with a number of different 3D examples in Silverlight.

Another useful source of information would be [Charles Petzold's book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/3D/) (you should buy it) and [blog](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/01/Non-Affine-Transforms-in-Silverlight.html). It is mostly about WPF 3D, but the concepts will be applicable to Kit3D (and Silverlight 3.0, presumably, when it's announced next week).

Answer (score 0):

Wait for Silverlight 3.  This should be out this summer some time and supports 3D, but your questions aren't related to 3D.

Currently Silverlight 2 supports all of that functionality yo described.  To get some information on what this entails I would suggest downloading Blend and playing with the transform propertied, rotation, scale are all a part of that functionality.

As for resize and drag and drop that's a whole other beast.  On your control you'll have to add some methods on the event handlers for LeftMouseButtonDown and LeftMouseButtonUp, then capture the mouseposition delta to get which direction and how far to move, then apply that to the transformgroup property of TranslateTransform on the X or Y plane.

You're clearly going to have to do some work to get at what you want to achieve.